# desplazarse por un ScrolledText (python)

Tags: python

Muy buenas por lo pronto decir que estoy medio-empezando con python, por lo que si digo alguna burrada me sea perdonada.

Tengo metido en un ScrolledText un fichero grande(45.000 lineas mas o menos) y quisiera implementar un entry y un botón por el cual pueda poner una linea y desplazarme hasta ella sin usar el ratón para desplazarme dentro del Scrolledtext..No se si hay alguna forma de hacer que el 'digamos focus´del scrolledtext pase a esa linea....

muchas gracias de antemano...

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Tu pregunta quedaria mucho mejor si compartes el código que tienes hasta el momento y explicandolo desde ahi. Un saludo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer un scroll automático hasta una cierta línea del texto, tienes que conocer las "coordenadas" del texto en cuestión (fila y columna). Por ejemplo, si sabes que el texto está en la línea 10, columna 3, la posición será `"10.3"`.

Puedes encontrar en qué posición está un texto dado si lo buscas dentro del widget a través de su método `search`. Por ejemplo:

```
# La variable t es una instancia de ScrolledText()
# en la cual ya has insertado algún texto mediante `t.insert()`

posicion = t.search("texto buscado", "1.0", "end")
```

Donde `"1.0"` es la posición desde la que comienza la búsqueda (línea 1, columna 0) y `"end"` es la posición hasta donde quieres buscar (la cadena `"end"` representa el final del texto). Si el texto es encontrado, te retornará una cadena como por ejemplo `"10.3"`, que contiene línea y columna donde se encontró. Si no ha sido encontrado te retorna una cadena vacía.

Para que el widget haga *scroll* hasta ese punto, basta que le pidas que esas coordenadas sean "visibles", mediante algo como:

```
if posicion:  # Si no es la cadena vacía
   t.see(posicion)
```

A `t.search()` le puedes pasar una expresión regular para búsquedas más avanzadas, en cuyo caso debes añadirle el parámetro `regexp=True`.